# Project cannot locate imported d3-graphviz module

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ember.js, d3-graphviz

The project is located at https://github.com/eric-g-97477/blog-ember-d3 which is a fork of [this](https://www.mediasuite.co.nz/blog/the-lost-guide-to-starting-with-ember-and-d3/) project.

The output of `npm list` is:

```
$ npm list                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
blog-ember-d3@0.0.0
├── @ember/jquery@0.6.0
├── @ember/optional-features@0.7.0
├── broccoli-asset-rev@3.0.0
├── d3-graphviz@4.1.1
├── d3-selection@3.0.0
├── d3@5.9.2
├── ember-ajax@5.0.0
├── ember-cli-app-version@3.2.0
├── ember-cli-babel@7.7.3
├── ember-cli-dependency-checker@3.1.0
├── ember-cli-eslint@5.1.0
├── ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile@2.1.0
├── ember-cli-htmlbars@3.0.1
├── ember-cli-inject-live-reload@1.10.2
├── ember-cli-sri@2.1.1
├── ember-cli-template-lint@1.0.0-beta.3
├── ember-cli-uglify@2.1.0
├── ember-cli@3.10.1
├── ember-d3@0.5.1
├── ember-data@3.10.0
├── ember-export-application-global@2.0.0
├── ember-load-initializers@2.0.0
├── ember-maybe-import-regenerator@0.1.6
├── ember-qunit@4.4.1
├── ember-resolver@5.1.3
├── ember-source@3.10.0
├── ember-welcome-page@4.0.0
├── eslint-plugin-ember@6.4.1
├── eslint-plugin-node@9.0.1
├── loader.js@4.7.0
└── qunit-dom@0.8.5
```

I am trying to import by doing:

import { graphviz } from "d3-graphviz";

and that generates the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `d3-graphviz` imported from `blog-ember-d3/libs/donut-chart`
```

I am sure this is something silly, but I am not sure what has gone wrong.

My goal was to start with a d3 based project that worked and determine how to get d3-graphviz working within it.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `ember-auto-import`, you should be able to import from `d3-graphviz`.  ember-auto-import sets up webpack and allows things to "just work" from npm, and is standard in all ember apps since ember-cli 3.16

Also, if you're starting a new app, you may want to update `ember-cli` so you get the latest blueprint.

```bash
npm install -g ember-cli@latest
```